# Make a submit form work without redirecting or refreshing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a php contact form with some js script. In that form when the submit button (input) is clicked (if all the inputs are filled correctly) a "success" message will appear under the form, but it can't be seen because the page is redirecting to the contact.php file. I want the form to work without redirecting, so just to appear that success message under the form and to CLEAR all the inputs after submit (if all the inputs was filled correctly). I would really appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.
I can't put php in jsfiddle, but I think it is not needed for what I want.
Here is the rest of the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/5nLab5kh/

HTML:

```
 <form role="form" id="form-contact" method="post" action="php/contact.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactName">Your Name (required)</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="ContactName" id="ContactName" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ContactEmail">Email Address (required)</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control required" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="ContactMsg">Your Message</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  name="ContactMsg" title=""></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit" id="ContactMessage"/>
  </form>
  <p id="cf-notification"></p>
```

JS:

```
$('#form-contact').submit(function(){

/* Get Values */
contact_name    = $('#ContactName').val();
contact_email   = $('#ContactEmail').val();
contact_message = $('#ContactMsg').val();

/* Validate Fields */
if( contact_name == '' ){
    $('#cf-notification').hide().html('<span class="alert"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Please fill your contact name!</span>').fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
}else if( contact_email == '' ){
    $('#cf-notification').hide().html('<span class="alert"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Please fill your email address!</span>').fadeIn("slow");
    return false;

}else if( contact_message == '' ){
    $('#cf-notification').hide().html('<span class="alert"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Please fill your message!</span>').fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
}else{$('#cf-notification').hide().html('<span class="success"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>' + 'Thank you for contacting us! We will answer as soon as we can.' + '</span>').fadeIn("slow");
    return true;
}
```

});

Comment: *"I want the form to work without redirecting"* - if you just want to clear the inputs and don't want to redirect, then why are you using a submit button? why not a simple button? why have to specified the from action?? if you want to hit the other page without redirection, then look into ajax.

Comment: Ok, I make it to clear in the case in which it was submitted with succes. Now is not redirecting (because I put "return false" in the else section) but it is not working, not sending any email. Any very simple idea? Not to remake everything and waste my time with ajax?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by - * it was submitted with succes*? the data was sent to somewhere else for processing? if you want to do that without page refresh then you're gonna need ajax.

Comment: I played a little bit with js and solved it :) Thanks in anyway :)

Comment: well whatever you just posted is indeed an ajax request ;)

Answer (score 0):

It was solved. For who is interested in "else" you have to replace "return true" with this:

```
$("#form-contact")[0].reset();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
  },'json');
  return false;
```

The first line is just clearing the inputs, the rest is solving the redirect problem :). So works perfectly and no redirect.

Comment: were did this code come from? it isn't there in question? 0__0